# How to get junit report when testcase is executed from java class?

Tags: java, junit, report, automated-tests, keyword

I'm developping a keyword drivent testing framework.

I'd like to get the html report of a junit testcase called within a java class.
I'm able to get the html report when the testcase itself is call in a ant task : build, testcase_model, junit.

But I'd like to have this ; build, DriveTest (the java class calling the testcase_model), junit. Unfortunately this doesn't generate a report.

I call my testcase like this :

```
JUnitCore junit = new JUnitCore();
junit.addListener(new TextListener(System.out));
Result result=junit.run(TestCase_Model.class);
```

Thank you very much people.
Jean

/!\ UPDATE /!-------------------------------------------------

Hello. For now I put aside the "@RunWith(SomeRunner.class)" way. In my DriveTest class I call my TestCase_Model like this : 
`JUnitCore junit = new JUnitCore();
RunListener listener = new RunListener();
junit.addListener(listener);
Result result = junit.run(TestCase_Model.class);`.

My DriveTest target looks like this : 
`<target name="DriveTest (5)">
        <mkdir dir="${junit.output.dir}" />
        <junit fork="yes" printsummary="withOutAndErr">
            <formatter type="xml" />
            <test name="tech.DriveTest" todir="${junit.output.dir}" />
            <classpath refid="RWD_Testing.classpath" />
        </junit>
    </target>`.

I finally get the report but I just have a global result and not a detailled result (testRun1 -> success, testrun2 -> success). What seems wrong to you ?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't make DriveTest a JUnit Suite?

Comment: Thank you for answering MrPotes. Well I tried to make DriveTest a junit testcase (public class DriveTest implements junit.framework.Test) but it didn't change anything. So I guess it will be the same with a testsuite ?

Comment: Perhaps you can give a bit more detail about what TestCase_Model actually does? Are you using JUnit 3 or 4?

Comment: Sure ! My TestCase_Model have a @ Parameters data() method which iterate with parameters. And a @ Test run() method that iterates through an array of methods. These methods are my keywords, and these methods make assertions, among other. I'm using Junit4.

Comment: I think you probably want to define a runner that then generates tests - see the answer below.

Comment: It's not so much "wrong" as not quite the best way to make use of the JUnit library. I don't know how your TestCase_Model actually causes tests to be run, but if you use the runner you can make sure that the test classes that you run actually contain tests - here you seem to have a test class that actually isn't a test at all. But like you say, it works.

Comment: Hello MrPotes. "here you seem to have a test class that actually isn't a test at all" : You're right, the DriveTest doesn't implement any junit class, but my main method running the junitcore have a @Test annotation. I'm gonna try to make a best use of the JUnit library.

Answer (score 0):

Most testing frameworks that allow running to be wrapped up in a JUnit execution use a JUnit Runner, which can then be applied to a class using the `@RunWith` annotation.

For example, see Cucumber-JVM's [`Cucumber`](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/master/junit/src/main/java/cucumber/api/junit/Cucumber.java) runner, which runs .feature files from a test declared as follows:

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
private class RunCukesTest {
}
```

All the logic for finding and executing tests is done in the runner, but because it's still a JUnit test that gets run, all the JUnit report generation works as expected.

Comment: Thank you for your very valuable answer MrPotes. I'm gonna try with a testrunner class and I keep you updated.

Comment: Actually I don't get what I should put in my runner class (the Cucumber.class in your example, right ?) ? My DriveTest class should use that runner with @RunWith(MyOwnRunnerclass.class) ?